# Why doesn't my Magento shopping cart rule work with different product types?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I work for an ecommerce site.

We have a shopping cart rule that when a customer adds five items to their basket the cost of one of those items is removed from the balance. We advertise this as "Buy four items get one free."

However, we distinguish between "Standard" and "premium" product types on our back end and the rule does not activate for mixed baskets. The rule works for baskets of 5 premium products and baskets of 5 standard products but not mixed baskets of 5.

This is how the rule appears on the back-end:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L1Dq.png

And on the action tab:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/If9o7.png

What is wrong with this shopping cart rule?

Comment: Please send us also an image , from the Action tab also.
What you posted is only from the conditions (when should magento check this rule). More important is this part:
"Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)". As I wrote you can find it in the Actions tab.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a picture from the action tab now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the new image.
Well looks like yo try to do this with Buy x get Y free method, what could be utilized only with the same product.
You could use an different approach to create your conditions, like:

Apply the rule only if the following conditions:

> If total quantity equals or greater than 4 for a subselection of items
>   in cart matching ANY of these conditions:
>   type is ...
>   type is ....

[image]

After this modify you Actions tab, and apply an another rule type, like percentage, or fixed discount, what you want.
With this change, your mixed basket will work also!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked and I was also able to work out how to add a 20% discount to the cart as well. You have really helped me out!